# How to sum distinct subsets of rows into distinct new columns in SAS?

Tags: sas

I want to compute multiple sums on the same column based on some criteria. Here is a small example using the `sashelp.cars` dataset.

The code below somewhat achieves what I want to do in three (3) different ways, but there is always a small problem.

```
proc report data=sashelp.cars out=test2;
    column make type,invoice type,msrp;
    define make / group;
    define type / across;
    define invoice / analysis sum;
    define msrp / analysis sum;
    title "Report";
run;

proc print data=test2;
    title "Out table for the report";
run;

proc summary data=test nway missing;
    class make type;
    var invoice msrp;
    output out=sumTest(drop= _Freq_ _TYPE_) sum=;
run;
proc transpose data=sumTest out=test3;
    by make;
    var invoice msrp;
    id type;
run;
proc print data=test3;
    title "Table using proc summary followed by proc transpose";
run;

proc sql undo_policy=none;
    create table test4 as select 
        make,
        sum(case when type='Sedan' then invoice else 0 end) as SedanInvoice,
        sum(case when type='Wagon' then invoice else 0 end) as WagonInvoice,
        sum(case when type='SUV' then invoice else 0 end) as SUVInvoice,
        sum(case when type='Sedan' then msrp else 0 end) as Sedanmsrp,
        sum(case when type='Wagon' then msrp else 0 end) as Wagonmsrp,
        sum(case when type='SUV' then msrp else 0 end) as SUVmsrp
    from sashelp.cars
    group by make;
quit;
run;
proc print data=test4; 
    title "Table using SQL queries and CASE/WHEN to compute new columns";
run;
```

Here is the result I get when I run the presented code.

[image]

The first two tables represent the result and the out table of the `report` procedure. The problem I have with this approach is the column names produced by `proc report`. I would love to be able to define them myself, but I don't see how I can do this. It is important for further referencing.

The third table represent the result of the `proc summary`/`proc transpose` portion of the code. The problem I have with this approach is that `Invoice` and `MSRP` appears as rows in the table, instead of columns. For that reason, I think the `proc report` is better.

The last table represents the use of an `SQL` query. The result is exactly what I want, but the code is heavy. I have to do a lot of similar computation on my dataset and I believe this approach is cumbersome.

Could you help improve one of these methods ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use two PROC TRANSPOSE steps;

```
proc summary data=sashelp.cars nway missing;
  where make=:'V';
  class make type;
  var invoice msrp;
  output out=step1(drop= _Freq_ _TYPE_) sum=;
run;
proc transpose data=step1 out=step2;
  by make type ;
  var invoice msrp;
run;
proc transpose data=step2 out=step3(drop=_name_);
  by make;
  id type _name_ ;
  var col1 ;
run;
proc print data=step3;
  title "Table using proc summary followed by 2 proc transpose steps";
run;
```

Results:

```
                                                  Sedan       Sedan       Wagon       Wagon
Obs    Make          SUVInvoice     SUVMSRP     Invoice        MSRP     Invoice        MSRP

 1     Volkswagen      $32,243      $35,515    $335,813    $364,020     $77,184     $84,195
 2     Volvo           $38,851      $41,250    $313,990    $333,240     $57,753     $61,280
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Proc TABULATE`.  Very succinct expressions for specifying row and column dimensions defined by desired hierarchy of class variables.

The intersection of these dimensions is a cell and represents a combination of values that select the values for which a statistical measure is displayed in the cell.

In your case the `SUM` is sum of dollars, which might not make sense when the cell has more then one contributing value.

For example: Does it make sense to show the `invoice` `sum` for `11` `Volkswagen` `Sedan`'s is `$335,813` ?

Also note the 'inverted' hierarchy used to show the number of contributing values.

Example:

```
proc tabulate data=sashelp.cars;
  class make type;
  var invoice msrp;

  table 
    make=''
    ,
    type * invoice * sum=''*f=dollar9.   
    type * msrp    * sum=''*f=dollar9.   /* this is an adjacent dimension */

    (invoice msrp) * type * n=''   /* specify another adjacent dimension, with inverted hierarchy */

    /
    box = 'Make'
  ;

  where make =: 'V';
run;
```

Output
[image]